# Anyway to restore An old iphone 5 images and videos?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, restore

I have my old iPhone 5 and I want to restore the old deleted images on it:
for context, it had a lock button problem and when I gave it to my phone company to fix it they deleted everything on it the only things that were restored are only the 5 GB from the iCloud and the other 10 GB worth of data were lost
is there any way to restore these 10 GB that wasn't saved by the iCloud

Comment: Do you have an old backup on Mac via iTunes or Finder, or Time Machine?

Comment: I could have seen something similar on my old PC but i couldn't access it, it was encrypted